# GeoServer GeoTIFF not rendering properly in QGIS and GeoServer Previews

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms

I have a WMS raster ortho image that I have published as a GeoTIFF on two different GeoServers, a development server and a test server. On the dev server the image can be previewed in GeoServer just fine. In the test server the preview is invisible except for the black 'noData' around the perimeter. Both instances of the raster were published the same way in two different GeoServers.

When I open both the WMS layers in QGIS, the image is displayed incorrectly and only as a single band instead of the four bands (RGB + alpha).

What's happening?

This is how it looks displayed in QGIS but also looks that way in GeoServer. 
[image]

QGIS only recongizes a single band
[image]

EDIT: It appears that I can see the layers when I zoom in to certain extents using both GeoServer and QGIS but not at the default extent and not at other extents when the WMS is brought in to QGIS/previewed in GeoServer.

[image]

Comment: 1.Check your SLD applied on Geoserver ,it might contains min/max scale. 2. Regarding alpha band : we removed band while exporting tiff format and then it was working fine

Comment: please add the gdalinfo output for your image.

Comment: @IanTurton I'm fairly new to GeoServer. How do I do that? Or is that just the Layer Properties->Information in QGIS?